# Organizing code in c# using 1 Form and a lot of functions

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I am writing a program that has like 8 tabs in one form. Each tab does different functionality so as you know it requires a lot of methods/variables/classes/background workers etc..

I used to write similar programs before but the MainForm.cs file had a lot of code and it made it very messy( a lot of controls, on click events, etc..)

What is the best way to organize the code in such case?

Are there any documents or examples to follow?

Please let me know!

Comment: @bluetoft Pretty sure this question is related to WinForms and not ASP.NET. Circler, if you are eager to break out your code and not deal with the uglyness that comes with Win Forms, I suggest looking into WPF and MVVM.

Comment: @bluetoft yes it is related to WinForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything HAS to be in one class, I'd try partial classes out. You can make a new .cs file for every tab and add it to your project, but everything will still be in the same class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: can I handle click events, tables etc..  tablelayoutpabel for example from those partial classes ?

Comment: Sure can. You can create separate files for those as well, like MainForm_Events.cs or something.

Answer (score 2):

Create user controls for each tab page and place all control in their separate user control for each page. Thus, your code will be separated in their usercontrol. You can also invoke their method and handles it's events from your main form.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is [MDI Child Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Each tab can be created as a separate form then added during initialization.  I also believe you can drop these into a tab form, [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12514/Multi-Document-Interface-MDI-tab-page-browsing-wit).

Good luck!

Comment: your solution is good when we are handling each page separately. It may be difficult to get data from all tab pages in a single button click.